# Blazor Wasm (No WebApi) Google Sheets Authorization

Tags: c#, google-sheets, blazor-webassembly

I would like to create a Blazor Wasm application to access a Google Sheets document.
Following the guideline (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet)
I have the following code:

```
public static class GoogleSheetsService
{
    public static async void Authenticate()
    {
        string[] scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        var applicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

        var clientsecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "....apps.googleusercontent.com", 
            ClientSecret = "..."
        };

        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            clientsecrets,
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new MyDataStore());

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName,
        });

   ....
    }
}
```

I created an own implementation of the IDataStore as MyDataStore, because of the file handling. (I prefer to save the given credentials in local storage, avoid file usage).

When running the code the following error shows up (just the first part, much longer):

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Unhandled Exception:
>
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.PlatformNotSupportedException:
> Operation is not supported on this platform.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
> addressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType,
> System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType) <0x3028760 + 0x0003c> in
> :0
>
> blazor.webassembly.js:1   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener..ctor
> (System.Net.IPAddress localaddr, System.Int32 port) <0x301c470 +
> 0x0006e> in :0

So my question is, what is going wrong and it is possible to access a Google Sheets document this or any other way using only Wasm?

Comment: Credentials are obtained from a ```.json``` file stored locally. In Quickstart, this file is obtained in the line ```New FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;``` where ```credPath``` is the path to this credentails file. As you have changed that line with ```MyDataStore()``` you are not retrieving the credentials file. I think you would need to pass it as a parameter. Let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile I found this article: https://medium.com/@semuserable/net-core-google-sheets-api-read-write-5edd919868e3 and this approach is solved my problem after some modification.

Comment: HI ! Could you please post as an answer to your question the modification points that solved your issue so that other users with similar problems can easily find the solution? Many thanks !